# In a non-abelian group, if $C(a)=\langle a\rangle$ then $a\not\in Z(G)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $G$ is a non-abelian group and $a∈G$. Prove that if $C(a)= \langle a \rangle$ then $a\not\in Z(G)$. I just don't understand this proof at all. Would someone mind walking me through the entire proof?

Answer (score 8):

The element $a$ is in the center $Z(G)$ if and only if it commutes with all elements in $G$. This is equivalent to saying that the centralizer of $a$ is all of $G$. Compare the definitions of the center and centralizer and make sure you understand this.

Now, we're being told $C(a) = \langle a \rangle$. If $a$ were in $Z(G)$, we would have $G = C(a) = \langle a \rangle$. But $\langle a \rangle$ is abelian (being cyclic), while $G$ is not. Thus, $a$ cannot be in the center $Z(G)$.

Comment: How do we know that since <a> is commutative, that a cannot be in zg=gz for all g in G? I do not understand how we can leap from knowing that since <a> is abelian, it cannot be in the center. I appreciate your helpfulness

Comment: @LeviNols: By definition, $C(a)$ consists of all elements commuting with $a$.

Comment: @LeviNols If the element $a$ were in the center, we would have $C(a) = G$. Do you see why this is true? Now, we are told that $G$ is not abelian so $C(a) \ne G$. This means that $a$ cannot be in the center.

Answer (score 1):

Since $C(a) = \langle a\rangle$ is abelian and $G$ is not, $C(a) \neq G$. Now $a\notin Z(G)$, because otherwise by definition $C(a) = G$.